# deserialize a datatable/dataset created from an xsd file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datatable, xsd

I have created a dataset using ReadXmlSchema("file.xsd"). The xsd file has datatypes like "STRING_50". While debugging, it seems I cannot see any strange datatypes for the datatable columns, i.e. the datatable is filled correctly with data, and the datatypes of columns are either string or int32.

But the problem is when I deserialize (code: new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(stream)) the datatable at the server side I do get this error:
{"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}
{"Type 'STRING_50' is not declared, or is not a simple type."}
or 
{"Type 'INTEGER' is not declared, or is not a simple type."}

It seems that those types are not serializable. But how can I make them serializable? And why when I look at the datatypes of the table columns, I only find string and Int32, I don't get those strange types like string_50, or INTEGER?
How can I deserialize my datatable?

I have tried a dirty work around and it worked. I have created a new datatable (I will call it datatable2), and I have just copied the values from the original datatable (datatable1) to datatable2. When I send datatable2 over to the server, it works. But I really want to avoid this workaround. I want to know what is the issue with the datatable1, I don't want an extra nested loop for copying data to another datatable (datatable2).

I have also executed the command dt.WriteXml(path,XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema) for datatable1 and datatable2. For datatable1 I get the "Object reference not set to an instance...", but for datatable2, it works perfectly fine. As I mentioned, datatable2 contains all data in datatable1, and the same number of columns and column names.

Comment: I would write dataset using ds.WriteXml("filename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);  The it is automatic when you read dataset the schema is automatically read and you don't need a separate file.

Comment: Use XmlSchema in conjunction with xml serialization, but not with the BinaryFormatter.

Comment: @jdweng I have edit my question. For the original datatable, I get the "Object reference..." exception when trying this command. But I can see all the data in the datatable while debugging!!

Comment: STRING_50 is the type Name in c# (a string with 50 characters max).  It looks like instead of getting the value of the column you are getting type.  This often happens when you use the ToString() method in c# incorrectly.

Comment: @jdweng I used ds.ReadXmlSchema to build the dataset/datatable. While debugging when I look datatable1.Columns[0].DataType.Name, I get "String". I never get String_50 or any of those types in xsd. Only while deserializing, I get an error because it doesn't recognize string_50!! I don't know where in datatable properties is string_50 saved. Also I don't know why I get an error when I try to use WriteXml(path,XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema) against datatable1.

Comment: If you are writing a datatable, the table must have a name to use WriteXml() method.  A dataset doesn't need the name.